# How to programmatically remove the background of an image making it transparent in android

Tags: android, image

How to programmatically remove the background of an image making it transparent in android.

Is it straight forward to remove the background of the photo/image in android? 
What is the approach. 
Do we have any existing api already?

In am basically looking to remove the image background and to add new background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for image processing you can use OpenCV http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *straight forward*, but image processing is almost never a trivial matter. So you are probably looking for something like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

Comment: Link shows following error: The page you are looking for no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove background you need to perform image segmentation first. You need to define what part of image is object which you want to preserve and which part is the background. Then you could switch background. Please provide some sample image you want to process.

Unless that images have some simple background like for example single color background without noise, algorithm has to be fitted to process some specific kind of images. No such algorithm exists that could segment all random images.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for.The image will be simple object with the single color background with no or less background noise. So in such case do we have any api or third party library available to achieve.